# Which Flurry library should I use for universal iPhone/iPad apps?

Tags: iphone, ipad, analytics, flurry

Flurry has a separate analytics SDK for iPad apps vs iPhone apps.  If I'm building a universal app to run on the iPhone 4.0+ and iPad 3.2+ (iPad native, not compatibility mode), does anyone know which SDK/lib I should use?  And is there any reason I shouldn't use the same SDK/lib for apps running on iPhone 4+ only?  (Basically, I'm confused as to why there are separate SDKs at all.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the latest 3.0.7 Flurry SDK version both libraries and headers are identical (tested with md5). Looks like they have merged both branches, possibly as of the 3.0 version. They should make that clear by releasing a common iOS SDK but the answer to your question is now clear: either one will do.

Answer (score 22):

Since you would like to have your new application work on both the iPhone and iPad please use Flurry's iPhone SDK.

If you have an application that is only meant to work on the iPad please use Flurry's iPad SDK.

Comment: For those flagging this as spam, this appears to be a legitimate response by Flurry to a question about their product.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what advantage there is to using the iPad-only SDK, since the iPhone SDK will also work on the iPad?

Comment: Dear Flurry, maybe you should make this clearer during app creation, instead of making folks go search for the info...

Answer (score 3):

I think the iPhone 4.0+ SDK may work properly on iPad. I have this address where you can ask directly to Flurry Support, they always give me an answer to my questions.

Flurry iPhone/iPad Support
iphonesupport@flurry.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a difference in the Flurry library, they are the same for iPhone and iPad. I think the only difference is when you first set up an application, it asks what platform you're targeting, perhaps just for their own metrics.

Comment: This isn't true. The binaries are different. (I don't know in what way, but they aren't the same...)

Answer (score 0):

A universal aap can be tracked by the iphone sdk.you can also  track it separately.then you should use iphone and ipad sdk both.

[that is the link at where i found the information for same](https://flurry.zendesk.com/entries/21386688-how-do-i-configure-a-universal-app-how-do-i-track-a-universal-app)